# Install own R package via function in R

Tags: r, package

When I build my own package in RStudio I click on "Install and restart" in the Build-tab. I'm wondering if I could do this via a function. I've seen that some code is running (`meinpaket` is the package's name):

`Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source meinpaket`

So I've tried the following:

`system("Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source meinpaket")`

I've tried it with `shell`, too.

I get the following error message:

`Warning: invalid package 'meinpaket' Error: ERROR: no packages specified`

Comment: The ?install.packages indicates you can point it at a directory.  Of course if you are using github you can use install_github(). Or zip your folder up and install from that.

Comment: Thank you! zipping up is the way I like. You can post this comment as an answer if you want, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip your package (use the "build from source" command in RStudio to do the whole process including help and vignetts) and then install.packages() pointing to the zip file.